# Cisco 2950 - 3550 with a straight through cable

Tags: cisco, layer1, cable, cabling

Everything I have read and experienced with both Cisco 2950 and 3550 switches seems to confirm the ports will not support Auto-MDIX. However yesterday when connecting a 3550 and 2950 I forgot to use a crossover cable. It worked anyway. Am I missing something?

Comment: which ports did you use?

Comment: Which are the part numbers of your devices? And which firmware versions are running?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, I've observed virtually all newer (by newer, I mean post-2005) Cisco switch and router platforms support auto-sensing - at minimum on GBIC/SFP interfaces, and usually on all ethernet interfaces. Even the Cisco 500 series small-business switches have support for it, although it's not clearly documented.

While the platforms do [mostly] support it, it's a good idea to assume the platform doesn't and use the proper cables anyway.